# Proper way to display UIView over all other and disable everything beneath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have little problem. I try to write code to show custom UIView (view does not cover full screen) over all others UIViews and enable to user interaction only with this one.

So I wrote code like this:

```
ResultView *resultView = [[ResultView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width-50)/2, (self.view.bounds.size.height-100)/2, self.view.bounds.size.width-50, self.view.bounds.size.height-100)];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE]; //for disable interaction
[self.view addSubview:resultView];
```

Now I should enable interaction only for top view, but I probably don't know how.

I try to do this also with UIViewController but without results.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 subviews instead of one. One transparent one that covers the view controllers entire view in order to prevent touches to it, and then add your `ResultView` as a subview to it.

Comment: There's no needs to make 2 subviews, it's even enough to create the only fullscreen subview with transparent bounds